# grep within a git diff, but show file and line number

Tags: git, diff

When I'm working on a branch, I want to quickly jump to my "TODO" comments.  This means

1. I only want "TODO" comments that were added on my branch (ignore the ones in master)
2. I want each match to show the file and line number.

I know two partial solutions: `git grep TODO` has the right format (with grep.lineNumber set to true), but too many results.  `git diff master... | grep TODO` is a good set of results, but doesn't show file and line number.

Is there an option to tell `git diff` to prefix each changed line with the filename and line number?  (`--line-prefix` looked promising but seems to take only a fixed string.)

Can I pass `--new-line-format=":%dn: %L"` ([diff - output line-numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34874/diff-output-line-numbers)) through `git diff`?

---

For example, currently my search results look like this:

```
$ git diff master... | grep TODO
+    // TODO use a non-fatal assertion
+        // TODO use a non-fatal assertion
+// TODO make this conditional too
```

But ideally I'd like this:

```
src/foo/abc.cpp:221:+    // TODO use a non-fatal assertion
src/foo/xyz.cpp:934:+        // TODO use a non-fatal assertion
src/foo/util/extra.h:49:+// TODO make this conditional too
```

Comment: This! Did you manage to get `src/foo/abc.cpp:221:+    // TODO use a non-fatal assertion` working?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `patch` mode of git log:

```
git log -p
# Hit '/' for search mode.
# Type TODO
# Then hit 'n' for next
```

To restrain to your branch you can add `firstcommit...HEAD`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the exact same thing as OP: find TODOs added on my branch.

So I put together a [diff2vimgrep](https://github.com/artemave/myrcs/blob/master/bin/diff2vimgrep) script. And then plugged it in [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) (a fuzzy finder for vim):

```
command! -bang -nargs=0 RgDiffMaster call fzf#vim#grep("git diff master... | diff2vimgrep", 0, {}, <bang>0)
```

And voila:
[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. From the [official git-grep documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) :

```
-h
-H
  By default, the command shows the filename for each match. -h option is used
  to suppress this output. -H is there for completeness and does not do
  anything except it overrides -h given earlier on the command line.

...

-n
--line-number
  Prefix the line number to matching lines.
```

This means that the following command

```
git grep -n TODO
```

should display all files containing "TODO" along with their name (default behaviour) and the line number for the match (with `-n`). Example output :

```
lib/my_script.py:67:    # TODO patch this
      ^          ^            ^
      |          |            |
  filepath    line number   matched line
```

If there are too many matches, you can use `:^some_folder` to exclude the folder `some_folder` from the grep search (see "Examples" paragraph) :

```
git grep -n TODO :^some_folder
```

or pipe shell commands like `sed` or `awk` to filter the output for only the files or folders you want.

Furthermore, you can set line numbers to be displayed by default (see "Configuration" paragraph) :

```
grep.lineNumber
  If set to true, enable -n option by default.
```

which can be set as explained in the different answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107059/how-to-show-line-numbers-by-default-with-git-grep-command), for example with :

```
git config --global grep.lineNumber true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I do have `grep.lineNumber` enabled, and I forgot it wasn't the default (I'll edit my question).  Can I restrict the search to lines I added, though?  I may have touched a file with dozens of existing TODOs.